# How can I confirm a "Sweet Alert" in a browser using a Python script?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, sweetalert

I'm looking to use Python 3.7 to automate a series of steps that I normally do manually in my Chrome 78 browser.  So far I've been able to use webdriver.chrome imported from selenium to handle opening pages in browser, entering username and password info, and clicking buttons.  But I'm stuck when I hit this ...

[image: Swal ("Sweet Alert")]

Is there a way to trigger this in the affirmative using a python code?  The bit of code that appears to be driving this alarm looks like this:

```js
function runSnapshot() {
      swal({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: 'Running snapshot will close orders for items.',
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                html: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
                cancelButtonText: 'No',
                closeOnConfirm: true,
                closeOnCancel: true
            },
            function (isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                        $.blockUI({ message: '<center><img src="/app/Content/spinner.gif" border="0"/></center>' });
                        $('#action').val('run'); $('form[name=snapshot]').addClass('ignoredirty').submit();
                    }
            });
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <p class="form-control-static input-large">
             Sat 23/11/2019 23:59:59
  </p>
  <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="runSnapshot()">Run</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck"?  Is there an error?  A silent failure?

Comment: I'm not even sure what to try.  I've been able to click html links using code similar to:  driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()  But I'm not even sure what Python code might work on this button embeded in Javascript

Comment: This:  driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Run').click() - will click the run button but then the "sweet alert" pops up and I don't know how to confirm it.

Comment: Try this: right click on the overlay (or ctrl-shift-i) to inspect the overlay and see the HTML.

Comment: Found this upon inspection:  <button class="confirm" tabindex="1" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(221, 107, 85); box-shadow: rgba(221, 107, 85, 0.8) 0px 0px 2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 0px 0px 1px inset;">Yes</button>

Comment: Got It!  This worked:

Comment: driver.find_element_by_class_name('confirm').click()

Comment: NP.  Glad you got it worked out.